# How can I copy the last line in a text file to another text file - batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I'm running curl through a batch file and print the output to a text file.
I want to copy the last line of this text file to another file so i'll have something like:

The first file:

```
  0  594M    0 1017k    0     0   813k      0  0:12:27  0:00:01  0:12:26  813k
  0  594M    0 2735k    0     0  1215k      0  0:08:20  0:00:02  0:08:18 1215k
  0  594M    0 5074k    0     0  1561k      0  0:06:29  0:00:03  0:06:26 1561k
  1  594M    1 6716k    0     0  1580k      0  0:06:25  0:00:04  0:06:21 1580k
  1  594M    1 8027k    0     0  1489k      0  0:06:48  0:00:05  0:06:43 1566k
  1  594M    1 8438k    0     0  1350k      0  0:07:30  0:00:06  0:07:24 1484k
  1  594M    1 8883k    0     0  1225k      0  0:08:16  0:00:07  0:08:09 1229k
  1  594M    1 9555k    0     0  1158k      0  0:08:45  0:00:08  0:08:37  896k
```

The second file:

```
 1  594M    1 9555k    0     0  1158k      0  0:08:45  0:00:08  0:08:37  896k
```

The batch file is:

```
curl -v -o NUL "http://...." 2>> file1.txt
timeout 10 /NOBREAK
copy /y file1.txt file1.tmp.txt 1>nul

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (file1.tmp.txt) do (
    set var_file1=%%a  
    )
echo !var_file1!
echo !var_file1! > file2.txt
```

The problem is that the first echo line prints the last line but the second line copy the **entire** file1 to file2.

What should I change in order to copy only the last line of file1 to file2 ?

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me.What cURL you are using? May it outputs its things in unix text format?

Comment: curl 7.37.1, how can I see if it is unix format?

Comment: check if the build is intended for cygwin or open the file with hex editor and see what the new lines look like the windows style is \r\n the unix style is \n

Comment: or download a cURL again - this the one I'm using - http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64.7z

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario I can think of where your code gives the results you describe is if the file you are receiving (file1.txt) uses a single carriage return (\r, 0x0D) as a line terminator.

If the file is always <~8190 bytes long when it uses \r as a line terminator, and the file never contains `!`, then you could use the following code to get the last line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

curl -v -o NUL "http://...." 2>> file1.txt

:: I don't see why this line is here, but it shouldn't do any harm
timeout 10 /NOBREAK

:: Read each line and store in a variable - Only the last line is preserved
:: If the file uses CR as a line terminator, then the entire file is stored
:: Maximum variable length is ~8190 bytes
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (file1.txt) do set "s=%%A"

:: Define CR as a carriage return
for /f %%A in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%A"

:: Define LF as a line feed
set ^"LF=^

^" This and the above empty line are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

:: The following is only needed if CR is the line terminator
:: But this does no harm if we already have the last line
for %%A in ("!CR!") do for %%B in ("!LF!") do (

  %= Remove existing LF =%
  set "s=!s:%%~B=!"

  %= Convert CR into LF =%
  set "s=!s:%%~A=%%~B!"
)

:: Get the last line for sure
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("!s!") do >test2.txt set "s=%%A"

:: Write the output file
>file2.txt echo(!s!
```

The limitation of no `!` in the file can be eliminated with extra code, but there is a much better way.

A robust and efficient solution is available using my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The code below assumes JREPL.BAT is in your current folder, or better yet, in a folder that is listed within your PATH. It will work with files that use \r, \n, \r\n, or \n\r as the line terminator.

```
@echo off

curl -v -o NUL "http://...." 2>> file1.txt

:: I don't see why this line is here, but it shouldn't do any harm
timeout 10 /NOBREAK

call jrepl "([^\r\n]+)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)?(?!.)" "$1" /m /jmatch /f file1.txt /o file2.txt
```

If you don't need file1.txt, then I believe you could do the following to get the result directly

```
@echo off
curl -v -o NUL "http://...." 2>&1 | jrepl "([^\r\n]+)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)?(?!.)" "$1" /m /jmatch /o file2.txt
```